# Candy Machine V2 - Trying to get all the nfts created by one candy machine

Tags: javascript, solana, metaplex

I am trying to figure out all the nfts that were created by one candy machine. I am so confused with the v2. Here is what I have done so far.

```
async function getProgramAccounts(
    connection,
    programId,
    configOrCommitment,
  ) {
    const extra = {};
    let commitment;
    //let encoding;
  
    if (configOrCommitment) {
      if (typeof configOrCommitment === 'string') {
        commitment = configOrCommitment;
      } else {
        commitment = configOrCommitment.commitment;
        //encoding = configOrCommitment.encoding;
  
        if (configOrCommitment.dataSlice) {
          extra.dataSlice = configOrCommitment.dataSlice;
        }
  
        if (configOrCommitment.filters) {
          extra.filters = configOrCommitment.filters;
        }
      }
    }
    const args = connection._buildArgs([programId], commitment, 'base64', extra);
    const unsafeRes = await (connection)._rpcRequest(
      'getProgramAccounts',
      args,
    );
  
    return unsafeRes.result;
  }
```

As per metaplex discord chat earlier. I need to get first creator that with this function

```
  const deriveCandyMachineV2ProgramAddress = async (
    candyMachineId,
  ) => {
    const candyMachineID = new PublicKey(candyMachineId);
    return await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [Buffer.from('candy_machine'), candyMachineID.toBuffer()],
      candyMachineProgram,
    );
  };
```

in order to fetch the hashTables as folllow

```
  const fetchHashTable = async (hash, metadataEnabled) => {
    const connection = new web3.Connection(
      process.env.REACT_APP_SOLANA_RPC_HOST
    );
    const creatorKey = await deriveCandyMachineV2ProgramAddress(hash)
  
    const metadataAccounts = await getProgramAccounts(
      connection,
      {
        filters: [
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset:
                1 +
                32 +
                32 +
                4 +
                MAX_NAME_LENGTH +
                4 +
                MAX_URI_LENGTH +
                4 +
                MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH +
                2 +
                1 +
                4 +
                0 * MAX_CREATOR_LEN,
              bytes: creatorKey,
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    );

    const mintHashes = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < metadataAccounts.length; index++) {
      const account = metadataAccounts[index];
      const accountInfo = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(account.pubkey);
      const metadata = new Metadata(hash.toString(), accountInfo.value);
      if (metadataEnabled) mintHashes.push(metadata.data);
      else mintHashes.push(metadata.data.mint);
    }
    console.log(mintHashes, 'minthashes')
    return mintHashes;
  };
```

The problem is that my function `getProgramAccounts` is not returning anything.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you need to `await` the connection args as well.

Comment: Thanks. I got this function from the metaplex github and I don't think await was there but I added it in case and still it is not returning anything.

Comment: is this duplicate with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710855/how-to-get-all-candy-machine-ids-on-solana-chain-by-web3-or-json-rpc/71913236#71913236

Comment: @skimah Have you found the solution for your issue? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

*deriveCandyMachineV2ProgramAddress* should return an array with 2 values so to get creator key you need access first element: `const [creatorKey] = await deriveCandyMachineV2ProgramAddress(hash)`  and this return a publicKey interface so just change `bytes: creatorKey` to  `bytes: creatorKey.toBase58()`