# How to get all Candy Machine Ids on solana chain by web3 or json rpc

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, solana

I wanna get all Candy Machine Ids on chain by web3 or json rpc call.
I have tried with getProgramAccounts json rpc but have response with Maximum response size reached.
Here is code I have tried.

```
curl http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed",
        "filters": [
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

How can I set filters to get Candy Machines only launched after specific date.
Or How to get only Publickey of CandyMachines in response.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you use the Typescript SDK.

You can use this function https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/ts/modules/utils.rpc.html#getMultipleAccounts or https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/ts/modules/utils.rpc.html#all to get multiple accounts. It will by default collect all the accounts owned by a public key.

You can then add a filter that matches a certain number of bytes within the struct you want to address. An example would be

````
let ownerBytes: GetProgramAccountsFilter[] = [{
        memcmp: {bytes: owner.toBase58(), offset: 8}
    }];
    let response = await program.account.userAccounts.all(ownerBytes);
    ```
````